# Command for retrieving for which architecture a library was built

Tags: shell

I remember that sometimes ago I was able to understand for which architecture a library (e.g. a `.so` or `.a` file) was built.

It was a shell command but now I cannot remember it.

Does somemone know it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but generally the `file` command gives this information:

```
$ file /lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0
/lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

You may also try readelf:

```
readelf -h /lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

More possible options:

```
$ objdump -a /lib/libc.so.6

/lib/libc.so.6:     file format elf64-x86-64
/lib/libc.so.6

$ objdump -f /lib/libc.so.6

/lib/libc.so.6:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x000000000001efc0
```

Comment: I'm not sure: objdump is a GNU tool. As far as I can see, FreeBSD/OpenBSD use them along with GNU compilers/linkers. Albeit OS X is usually very close to *BSD systems, I'm not 100% sure about it though - I don't have one here to check.

Comment: It doesn't work actually...maybe I have to download it, is it possible?